# Add two numbers stored as a list in F#

Tags: f#, integer

I am solving the following problem:

> You are given two lists representing two non-negative numbers. The digits are stored in reverse order and each of their nodes contain a single digit. Add the two numbers and return it as a list.

I wrote the following code:

```
let addTwoNumbers (a: int list) (b: int list) =
    let rec loop (a: int list) (b: int list) (c: int list) (carry: int) =
        match a, b, carry with
        | (h1::t1), (h2::t2), _ ->
            let q, r = Math.DivRem(h1 + h2 + carry, 10)
            loop t1 t2 (List.append c [r]) q
        | (h1::t1), [], _ ->
            let q, r = Math.DivRem(h1 + carry, 10)
            loop t1 [] (List.append c [r]) q
        | [], (h2::t2), _ ->
            let q, r = Math.DivRem(h2 + carry, 10)
            loop [] t2 (List.append c [r]) q
        | [], [], 0 ->
            c
        | [], [], carry ->
            let q, r = Math.DivRem(carry, 10)
            loop [] [] (List.append c [r]) q
    loop a b [] 0
```

Is there a way to simplify and possibly to de-duplicate some of this code?

Comment: Here's one way to split and concatenate digits into numbers, and the other way around: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31637121/126014

Comment: If this is a programming challenge, please consider adding the "programming challenge" tag and the source of the exercise if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`List.append` is an expensive O(*d*) operation, making your `addTwoNumbers` O(*d*<sup>2</sup>).  To reverse the list, you would be better off calling `List.rev` once at the end.  (By the way, `List.append c [r]` would be better written as `c @ [r]`.)

The `loop` helper function could use a better name.  My suggestions are either `add` or `addTwoNumbers'`.  I don't like the name `c` either, as it is somewhat mnemonically similar to `carry`.

Put the base cases first, followed by the recursive cases.

One of the cases can be simplified by taking advantage of commutativity.

When adding two numbers, `carry` should never be greater than 1.

```
let addTwoNumbers (a: int list) (b: int list) =
    let rec add (a: int list) (b: int list) (sum: int list) (carry: int) =
        match a, b, carry with
        | [], [], 0 ->
            sum
        | [], [], 1 ->
            1 :: sum
        | [], _, _ ->
            add b a sum carry
        | (h1::t1), [], _ ->
            let c, s = Math.DivRem(h1 + carry, 10)
            add t1 [] (s :: sum) c
        | (h1::t1), (h2::t2), _ ->
            let c, s = Math.DivRem(h1 + h2 + carry, 10)
            add t1 t2 (s :: sum) c
    add a b [] 0 |> List.rev
```

Answer (score 0):

If your inputs can be adjusted to the same length, prior to calling the function, you can leverage Zip and Fold and simplify the algorithm. (Instead of writing a recursive function and using pattern matching on 5 patterns.)

```
let addTwoNumbers digits1 digits2 = 

    let carryLast, answer = 
        Seq.zip digits1 digits2
        |>  Seq.fold
                (fun (carry, result) (v1, v2) -> 
                    let div, rem = Math.DivRem ( carry + v1 + v2 , 10)
                    (div, rem :: result)) 
                (0, [])

    if carryLast = 0
        then answer
        else carryLast :: answer
```